# Can't Move a dynamically created nested div from one div to another div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some dynamic div based on an input inside a parent div.

Now what I want to do is that if I click one of those created divs, it should move to other parent div and vice versa.

My code:

```
/*Html code*/

<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />
<div id="firstDiv">
<div id="1" class="a">Value</div>(Working over statically created div  )
</div>
<br>
--------------
--------------
-------------
<br>
<div id="SecondDiv">
<div id="4" class="b"> 
</div>
</div>
```

And JavaScript code:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSave').click(function() {
  addDiv($('#txtName').val());
  $('#txtName').val('');
  });
  $("div.a").on("click", function() {
  var $this = $(this);
 if ($this.hasClass("a")) {
    $this.removeClass("a").addClass("b").prependTo("#firstDiv");
 } else {
    $this.removeClass("b").addClass("a").prependTo("#SecondDiv");
 }
 });   

});

function addDiv(name) {
var container = $('#firstDiv ');
$('<div />', {class:'a',text:name }).appendTo(container).after("<br/>");
}
```

But the code is only working over already created div. I tested this, but it is not working for dynamically created div.

All I want is that I can create child div dynamically and move it to another div when clicked.

A [Sample Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Asifuzzaman/2kgu38am/5/) is also added

Comment: The event listener is only applied to the divs that match it when it is fired, you should look into [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This should get you where you need to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addDiv($('#txtName').val());
            $('#txtName').val('');
        });
         allowToggleDivLocation("div.a");
    });
    
    function allowToggleDivLocation(a){
        $(a).on("click", function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass("a")) {
                $this.removeClass("a").addClass("b").prependTo("#firstDiv");
            } else {
                $this.removeClass("b").addClass("a").prependTo("#SecondDiv");
            }
        });
    }
    
    function addDiv(name) {
        var container = $('#firstDiv '),
            c = $('<div />', {class:'a',text:name });
        allowToggleDivLocation(c);
        c.appendTo(container).after("<br/>");
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />
<div id="firstDiv">
<div id="1" class="a">Value</div>(Working over statically created div  )
</div>
<br>
--------------
--------------
-------------
<br>
<div id="SecondDiv">
<div id="4" class="b"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Didn't get to test it, but it should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#btnSave').click(function() {
            addDiv($('#txtName').val());
            $('#txtName').val('');
        });
         allowToggleDivLocation("div.a");
    });
    
    function allowToggleDivLocation(a){
        $(a).on("click", function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            if ($this.hasClass("a")) {
                $this.removeClass("a").addClass("b").prependTo("#firstDiv");
            } else {
                $this.removeClass("b").addClass("a").prependTo("#SecondDiv");
            }
        });
    }
    
    function addDiv(name) {
        var container = $('#firstDiv '),
            c = $('<div />', {class:'a',text:name });
        allowToggleDivLocation(c);
        c.appendTo(container).after("<br/>");
    }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSave" />
<div id="firstDiv">
<div id="1" class="a">Value</div>(Working over statically created div  )
</div>
<br>
--------------
--------------
-------------
<br>
<div id="SecondDiv">
<div id="4" class="b"> 
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works some how but on first time click it jumps one time then second click it moves could you please solve this??

Answer (score 0):

use `$(document).on("click", "div.a", function() {});` instead of `$("div.a").on("click", function() {});`

`$(document).on("click","element", function() {});` sees everything added to the DOM

`$("element")` only sees what is already in the DOM when the jquery code is loaded.

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2kgu38am/7/

Comment: Hello Thanks  for ur suggestion but will you check your fiddle ? when I am adding a new div base on the textbox that created div is not moving

Comment: @AsifuzzamanRedoy oh sorry, I linked the wrong one, its fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/2kgu38am/7/

Comment: Still not get It oky i am telling elaborately .If I Type A in textbox and click button a div will generate in firstDive dynamically when i click that div i want it to move created div(A) to secondDiv .if i add a new div its not moving to second div in your fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try using

`$(document).on('click', 'div.a', function(){ ... });`

This will allow the event to be attached to any dynamically-created `div.a` elements.